How to add a GIF keyboard support for an OutlinedTextField?
I am a beginner to developing Android apps using Jetpack compose
I have an OutlinedTextField in my app and I would like it to be able to receive GIFs from my default keyboard (at least the URL is enough for my application logic).
I have failed to find any code sample for this situation.  The official article here and here seem to be not applicable based on what I know.
